# How do I do a segmented line section in a line chart with iOS charts?

Tags: ios, iphone, linechart, ios-charts

You're wearing a heart rate monitor for most of the day, you take it off to shower, and then put it on. During that period it records no data or `0` so the a line, in a line cart depicting your hart rate, drops to the x-axis.

Is it possible to segment the line over the period you took it off rather than have it drop to the x-axis?

Answer (score 0):

By passing '0' values to iOS chart's line chart then it will drop x-values.

I suggest to make filter before passing values as '0', just remove though values. But you though values greater then '0' and going to display on line chart you can put date and time or only time.

So in line chart your requirement will get satisfy.